# Display all labelling name roads QGIS3.16

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I am trying to set an optimal scale to display all road names in order to make an atlas. I have already defined labelling rules (e.g. position: curved..., increase rotation, reduce the size...) in the layer properties of QGIS but with no conclusive result because I still have many unplaced labels. Do you have an idea? I thought of reducing my route names with an SQL query (e.g. John Smith -> J.Smith or Mary-Jane -> M-J) and so maybe use a function regexp?

It would also have a calculate unplaced label rate and stock this in database but I have not found anything about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reducing label name no need to use SQL or regexp, in the formatting tab check the "Apply label text substitutes" check box then click on the square on the right, it will let you load an xml file for abbreviation or manually input your own.
[image]

If you go this way (and use English in your map) you could go to [Examples of Ordnance Survey Abbreviations](http://www.geograph.org.uk/article/Ordnance-Survey---More-Abbreviations) to find lists that shouldn't be to hard to turn to XML for QGIS use.

Getting all road name label on city map is rarely doable using only automated placement and good result seem to need to manually adjust label position.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I didn't know about this option but I forgot to mention that the problem is that I have hundreds of thousands of records with different road names in my table

Comment: Sure but you could set road as Rd, Avenue as Ave. and so on. There are only a handful of road type, if you add the most frequent name and title you will be able to shorten most of your label (I was lucky enough to find an abbreviation dictionary in my language maybe you could find one in your). But I agree labeling is still the worst part of map making and you often either spend to much time to get it right or settle for good enough...